# How to remove hardcoded value for _T() in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

```
CAToolbar* pToolBarCommunicate = (CAToolbar*)pCommandBars->Add(new CAToolbar, _T("Comman Toolbar"), xtpBarTop);
```

I have this piece of code where the 'Common Toolbar' is hardcoded, I need to change it to some IDS mentioned in .rc file, shall I directly remove the text and replace with ID which is mentioned in .rc file with this text. something like `->Add(new CAToolbar, _T(IDS_COMMAN_TOOLBAR), xtpBarTop);`
is it correct way of doing this ? or is there any better way?

Comment: You probably have to get the string from the resource file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `MAKEINTRESOURCE`:

```
CAToolbar* pToolBarCommunicate = (CAToolbar*)pCommandBars->Add(
                        new CAToolbar, 
                        MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDS_COMMAN_TOOLBAR), 
                        xtpBarTop);
```

You can see more about it here: [`MAKEINTRESOURCEA` macro (winuser.h)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-makeintresourcea)

Comment: Or simply `CString str; str.LoadString(IDS_XXX); ..... new CAToolbar, str, ..);`